# h1 inside article or section when only one article is inside a section

Tags: html, css

I am trying my first parallax scrolling one page website and I realized there are a lot things that I can't make decisions in terms of html elements. Is it ok for a section element to not to have a header element (by header I mean h1,h2,etc or the header tag)?

I want to have the section element as the whole view with the background and have an article element that will hold all the content of that section, including the header.

Answer (score 0):

Use the hidden attribute on headers of html5 elements that you don't wish to display.

```
 <section>
     <h1 hidden>title</h1>
 </section>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute

To hide the element on browsers that do not support the hidden attribute use something like.

```
*[hidden] { display:none; }
```

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-hidden

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, check out the W3C specification. It mentions for `<section>`:

> The theme of each section should be identified, typically by including
>   a heading (h1-h6 element) as a child of the section element.

If you hide your title, you're applying a hack. If you don't include one, you'll be fine but your page will lack semantic structure. If your parallax background is a standalone element (not a container of the relevant content), then you should probably use a generic `<div>`.

In the [W3C Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/section) an example is given about article/ section markup. It would seem you should rather **design your parallax background as an `<article>` and `<section>` your content inside it.**

Comment: I don't believe that hiding the title is considered to be a hack, do you have more information on this? When I was first reading about html5 elements this was a suggested way to name html5 elements with that would have no visible title.

Comment: I just noticed I had posted the wrong link for the hidden attribute.

Comment: @threeandme, no it's not technically a hack. It's also not semantically a hack for the browser, it is only for the reader (who won't read it). And if the reader won't see it, why use a title at all instead of an id/ class? I'm not sure about how search engines treat `hidden` elements, but I wouldn't be surprised if they ignore them (due to the potential abuse of this attribute for malicious practices). That negates the benefit of using a heading element for SEO alltogether.

Comment: I think screen readers may pick them up, though I'm not sure. Otherwise the only reason to use would be for SEO purposes, I'm not sure if they are actually found though, will need to look it up. Swear I used to know this, no harm in brushing up though.

Comment: You're right, the `hidden` attribute is theoretically used by screen readers, as pointed out in [the examples here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/wiki/Correct_Hidden_Attribute_Section_v3). Let me know if you actually test this, or if you find their importance for SEO, I'm interested in the results!